# Load navigation menu using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter MVC framework. I want to load navigation menu for each page. This is my nav menu structure and please tell me how can I use codeigniter to create this.

```
    Home 
    **Category 01 --Cat01-to 04 load from Database
       SubCat01
       SubCat02
       SubCat03
    Category02
    Category 03
    Category 04**
    Contact
```

Comment: You'll notice this is getting a lot of downvotes. You may want to review the help files; in particular, [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [things to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You should using `URI Class` in codeigniter, and use suitable methods, like `uri_string` or `segment_array`.
[URI class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)